# Calling more than two web services with react js and populate them to a material ui dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this piece of code that call a web service and I have some questions.

The first one is, what is the best practice to call a second WS, now I just call one and display the data in a list but what if I have a second WS, should I call it inside the componentDidMout() method?

now I have an array called data but the for example, should I use a second array for a second WS call?

And the second one is, how can I populate the result of the WS in a material ui dropdown, I want to populate them with the data coming with the WS.

I'm new to react so some help would be nice.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';

export default class WebserviceTest extends Component {

 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    data: []
    };
 }

componentDidMount() {

const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=4';

 fetch(url).
 then((Response) => Response.json()).
   then((findResponse) => {
     console.log(findResponse);
     this.setState({
       data: findResponse.results
     });
 });

}
 render() {
 const listDesc = this.state.data.map((dt, i) =>
 <div>
   <div>
     <li key={i}>{dt.name.first}</li>
   </div>
 </div>
 );

 return (
    <div>
      <ul>{listDesc}</ul>
    </div>
   );
  }
}
```

The code above is working ok.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding populating the dropdown with data this should do the work.Haven't tested the code.Everything related to `material-ui/Dropdown` you can [check here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu).

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DropDownMenu from "material-ui/DropDownMenu";
import MenuItem from "material-ui/MenuItem";

export default class WebserviceTest extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: []
        };
        this.renderOptions = this.renderOptions.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=4";

        fetch(url)
            .then(Response => Response.json())
            .then(findResponse => {
                console.log(findResponse);
                this.setState({
                    data: findResponse.results
                });
            });
    }
    //will set wahtever item the user selects in the dropdown
    handleChange = (event, index, value) => this.setState({ value });
    //we are creating the options to be displayed
    renderOptions() {
        return this.state.data.map((dt, i) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <MenuItem key={i} value={dt.name.first} primaryText={dt.name.first} />
                </div>
            );
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DropDownMenu value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    {this.renderOptions()}
                </DropDownMenu>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

> What is the best practice to call a second Web Service??

**Answer**: Calling in `componentDidMount` is fine.Also it depends on other things.If both the WS calls are independent then you can call them using promise in parallels like:

```
Promise
    .all([
        fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=4').then((res) => res.json()),
        fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=4').then((res) => res.json()), 
    ])
    .then((response) => console.log(response)
    )
```

**Tip**: *If you will paste the above snippet in console, you will get the output.You can check the output.It returns an array of responses.*

> now I have an array called data but the for example, should I use a
>   second array for a second WS call?

It depends what you want to do with the data of second WS.If you want to add to the dropdown then you can simply concat with the `data` array.If want for some other purpose than you should keep the data separate.

> And the second one is, how can I populate the result of the WS in a
>   material ui dropdown, I want to populate them with the data coming
>   with the WS.

The code pasted in the beginning should work.You can simply map over data create options to be displayed in the list

Comment: Thanks for your time!!